# AD Token based authentication Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'. in entity framework 6 for Azure SQL

Tags: azure, entity-framework-6, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

I have done Azure AD authentication for my SQL database.
For that I followed bellow steps.

1. I set the Azure AD admin for the SQL database in the portal
2. List item
3. get authentication Token

   ```
   private static string GetAccessTokenAsync(string clientId, string clientSecret, string authority, 
   string resource, string scope)
   {
       var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, TokenCache.DefaultShared);
       var clientCred = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
       var token = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCred).Result.AccessToken;


       return token;
   }
   ```
4. did the sql connection

   ```
       string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADClientId"];
       string clientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADAppKey"];
       var authority = string.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}", tenantId);
       var resource = "https://database.windows.net/";
       var scope = "";
       try
       {
           var token = GetAccessTokenAsync(clientId, clientSecret, authority, resource, scope);

           var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
           builder["Data Source"] = $"{dbServer}.database.windows.net";
           builder["Initial Catalog"] = dbName;
           builder["Connect Timeout"] = 1500;
           builder["Persist Security Info"] = false;
           builder["TrustServerCertificate"] = false;
           builder["Encrypt"] = true;
           builder["MultipleActiveResultSets"] = false;

           SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(builder.ToString());
           con.AccessToken = token;
           return con;
       }
   ```
5. DB Context Class

   ```
    public partial class DBEntities : DbContext
       {
   //string dbConnectionString = 
         string.Concat(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["subdbconnectionstring"], '"', 
   string.Format(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbconnectionstring"], 
   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBPassword"]),'"');

   //string test = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["subdbconnectionstring"] + "\"" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbconnectionstring"];
   public DBEntities(SqlConnection con)
        : base(con, true)
   {
       {
           Database.SetInitializer<DBEntities>(null);
           ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 1800;
       }
    }
   ```
6. Finally connecting Database table

   ```
    var con = AuthenticationHelper.GetSqlConnectionAsync(Constants.CDSDBServer, Constants.CDSDBDatabaseName);
           using (var dbContext = new DBEntities(con))
           {

               var teamRolesList = await dbContext.TEAM_ROLE.
                                    Where(t=> t.IsDeleted.Equals(false))
                                   .Select(t => new TeamRole { RoleId = t.RoleId, RoleName = t.RoleName, IsDeleted = t.IsDeleted, UserInput=t.UserInput,AllowMultiples=t.AllowMultiples }).
                                   ToListAsync();
   ```

}

Now I am getting error while connecting to Table,

```
The underlying provider failed on Open.Login failed for user '<token-identified principal> 

at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.<OpenAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<EnsureConnectionAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<ExecuteInTransactionAsync>d__3d`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task 
  task)
at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<ExecuteAsyncImplementation>d__9`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<GetResultsAsync>d__e.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyAsyncEnumerator`1.<FirstMoveNextAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbAsyncEnumerableExtensions.<ForEachAsync>d__5`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at CompanyDataService.Controllers.TeamController.<GetAllTeamRoles>d__0.MoveNext() in D:\sol\vs_project\DataService\DataService\Controllers\TeamController.cs:line 32
```

Comment: Hmm, kinda looks like you are authenticating as an application. This application needs to be added to roles in the SQL database. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure?tabs=azure-powershell#create-contained-database-users-in-your-database-mapped-to-azure-ad-identities

Comment: Thanks Junnas for the comments..Yes added in Database

Comment: CREATE USER [App1] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'App1'

Comment: Hi, has this issue been resolved?

Answer (score 1):

In your steps, i don't see that you created an application registration in azure ad, but you seem to be using a clientid and secret. did you miss a step? Here's a full example of how to connect to sql database with a service principal:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-database/azure-ad-service-principal-authentication-to-sql-db-code-sample/ba-p/481467

Regards,

Comment: Thank you so much, I was getting error:  Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>', because in Visual Studio, the access token (jwt token) had the app id of Visual Studio rather than the app id of my dev principal.  I followed the tutorial from the link you posted and now my access token has the app id of my dev principal.